# Trying to show different banner images based on server time using PHP

Tags: php

I have four greeting images which I intend to show based on what time user enters the site.

```
$morning = "img/morning.png";
$afternoon = "img/afternoon.png";
$evening = "img/evening.png";
$night = "img/night.png";
```

And I have some conditional statements to assign the values to $cover variable. When I tested, the conditional statement doesn't work.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Yangon');
$Hour = date('G');

if($Hour >= 5 && $Hour <= 11) {
    $cover = $morning;
}elseif ($Hour >= 11 && $Hour <= 4) {
    $cover = $afternoon;
}elseif ($Hour >= 4 && $Hour <= 9){
    $cover = $evening;
}elseif ($Hour >= 9 && $Hour <= 4) {
    $cover = $night;
}
```

Img tag

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $cover; ?>" alt="Not Available" >
```

Comment: `date(G)` shows hours from 0 to 23.

Comment: What value will satisfy `$Hour >= 9 && $Hour <= 4`? `$Hour >= 11 && $Hour <= 4`?

Comment: your second and forth elseif don't make sense. There is no value to make this true:

`$Hour >= 11 && $Hour <= 4`  
`$Hour >= 9 && $Hour <= 4`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you just printed whatever `$Hour` contains to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       if($Hour >= 0 && $Hour <= 11) {
          $cover = $morning;
        }
        elseif ($Hour > 11 && $Hour <= 16) {
          $cover = $afternoon;
        }
        elseif ($Hour > 16 && $Hour <= 19){
          $cover = $evening;
        }
        else{
          $cover = $night;
        }
```

Above code will check your hours from 00:00 until 24:00 next day. I fixed your if-else statements so they make more sense in a way that there is a flow in the times.

> G 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23

Answer (score 0):

```
$hour = date('H', time());

if( $hour > 6 && $hour <= 11) {
 $cover = $morning;
}
else if($hour > 11 && $hour <= 16) {
   $cover = $afternoon;
}
else if($hour > 16 && $hour <= 23) {
   $cover = $evening;
}
else {
   $cover = $night;
}
```

Construct an instance of date and acquire the hour from it